# API Access Control Check

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, http

I'm accessing an external API from Javascript in my app and I get this error:

Failed to load http://www.myapp.com//api/v1/syndication/categories?output=json: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://local.myapp.com' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 400.

```
    function MakeAPIRequest(requestUrl, requestData, callback) {

    $.ajax({

        beforeSend: function(xhr){
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://local.myapp.com'); 
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Token', apiKey); 
        },
        type: "GET",
        url: requestUrl,
        data: requestData,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(json){
            callback(json);
        }

    });

}
```

Could be the API doesn't accept an "OPTIONS" request?
This is the server response:

{"error":"Bad Request -  Only accepts get requests","code":1009}

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is a response header. your www.myapp.com needs to support cors.

Answer (score 1):

`{"error":"Bad Request - Only accepts get requests","code":1009}` tells you that the server only accepts `GET` Requests while `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://local.myapp.com' is therefore not allowed access.` is a so called `cors` error.

You need to allow `CORS` on your server to get rid of this error.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Answer (score 0):

It is a CORS issue, the API you are calling resides on a different domain and the access control header does not allow requests from other domains.